# Passing bash code through the environment (for docker-compose)

Tags: shell, docker, sh, docker-compose

I am trying to deal with a known problem in docker-compose order of containers boot, so I ended with a simple solution, having a script to check if the environment is ready to start the command.

That is the idea, having some environment variable defined to the container:

- **WAIT_COMMAND** should be a string defining a logical test in sh script which has to return a boolean
- **START_CMD** a string with a command to run depending on the **WAIT_COOMAND** result, otherwise try again until **LOOPS** is reached.
- **LOOPS** how many times to try
- **SLEEP** how much to sleep between tryings

In that example I am waiting the elasticSearch to respond before starting my application which depends on ES data to boot.

The following script will be my ENTRYPOINT on docker container.

Exported ENV vars

```
WAIT_COMMAND="$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://elastic:9200/_cat/health?h=st) == 200"
LOOPS=3
START_CMD="python my_script_depending_on_elastic.py"
SLEEP=2
```

Having the above ENV vars available the script should wait until the ES request returns a code **200**

```
#!/bin/bash

is_ready() {
    eval $WAIT_COMMAND
}

# wait until is ready
i=0
while ! is_ready; do
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    if [ $i -ge $LOOPS ]; then
        echo "$(date) - still not ready, giving up"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "$(date) - waiting to be ready"
    sleep $SLEEP
done

#start the script
exec $START_CMD
```

The problem is that the code does not works in the line of **is_ready** function, it does not returns a boolean but tries to execute **200** as a command

```
# ./wait_elastic.sh 
./wait_elastic.sh: line 9: 200: command not found
Fri Jul  3 18:26:43 UTC 2015 - waiting to be ready
./wait_elastic.sh: line 9: 200: command not found
Fri Jul  3 18:26:45 UTC 2015 - waiting to be ready
./wait_elastic.sh: line 9: 200: command not found
Fri Jul  3 18:26:47 UTC 2015 - still not ready, giving up
```

How can I do the test to check if the curl response is ok?

How to specify a logical test command as:

```
WAIT_COMMAND="$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://elastic:9200/_cat/health?h=st) == 200"
```

and how to evaluate it:

```
is_ready() {
    eval $WAIT_COMMAND
}
```

?

Comment: BashFAQ #50 -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 -- is directly on-point.

Comment: As an aside, I'd also consider using modern math syntax: `i=$(( i + 1 ))`; `if (( i >= LOOPS ))`; etc. `$(( ))` is present in the POSIX standard; `(( ))` is a bash/ksh/zsh extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is bad practice. Please consider an approach which doesn't involve `eval` instead.

```
wait_command='[ $(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://elastic:9200/_cat/health?h=st) = 200 ]'
is_ready() {
  eval "$wait_command"
}
```

Differences from original code:

- Actually includes `test` command synonym `[` inside of the environment variable being evaluated (prior version was not legitimate bash comparison syntax).
- Switches from `==` (which is not a valid operator in POSIX `[`) to `=` (which is permitted by POSIX). See [the standards document for the `test` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).
- Switches from double-quotes to single-quotes at assignment time, such that `curl` isn't run until `eval` is called.
- Quotes the content passed to `eval` to prevent string-splitting and glob expansion from taking place before the code reaches the `eval` command.

---

Implementing this in the context of `docker-compose` might look like the following:

```
app:
    command: docker/wait
    environment:
        - wait_command=[ $(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://elastic:9200/_cat/health?h=st) = 200 ]
        - wait_loops=10
        - wait_sleep=30
```

...with a script something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
s_ready() { eval "$wait_command"; }

# wait until is ready
i=0
while ! is_ready; do
    if (( ++i >= wait_loops )); then
        echo "$(date) - still not ready, giving up"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "$(date) - waiting to be ready"
    sleep $wait_sleep
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I know this is bad to use eval, but until docker-compose team dont fix the issue of having a WAIT parameter I will use this. Thanks

Comment: I modified my other answer to demonstrate a representation of an exported function in YAML for use by docker-compose. Please do consider it.

Comment: I added that notes to the question

Comment: Indeed. (As an aside -- most of the time, editing questions to include an answer is frowned on here; if the accepted answer isn't good enough to help someone else with the same problem, the general approach is either to edit it to improve it, or to add another answer -- and indeed, for the person who asked a question to add their own answer if their real fix differs in a substantial way from any of the other answers on offer is encouraged. In terms of *why* this is encouraged -- the idea is that the OP's own answer should be subject to upvoting/downvoting same as any other).

Comment: OK, copied from question to this answer!

Comment: Accepted parts of that, with edits. `sh scriptname`  should never be used with a script starting with `#!/bin/bash`, since that runs it with `sh`, not `bash`, contrary to its shebang's statement regarding compatibility. Better to set the execute permission directly and let the shebang control startup. Also, using a `.sh` extension is not great practice -- bash scripts *are not* `sh` scripts, as above; moreover, commands on Unix don't have extensions by default -- you run `ls`, not `ls.elf` or `ls.coff`.

Comment: If this were a new enough release of bash, I'd also consider replacing the (slow) `date` call with the built-in, and thus much faster, `printf '%(%c)T - waiting to be ready\n' -1`.

Comment: ...it might also be possible to use `curl --fail`, and skip explicitly testing the HTTP status yourself altogether.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store code, don't use a scalar variable -- use a function; that's what they're for.

If you want to pass code through an environment variable, then the answer is an exported function:

```
wait_command() {
  [ $(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://elastic:9200/_cat/health?h=st) = 200 ]
}
export -f wait_command
```

...creates an environment variable that looks like the following (in modern, post-official-shellshock-patch bash):

```
BASH_FUNC_wait_command%%=() {  [ $(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://elastic:9200/_cat/health?h=st) = 200 ]
```

...which you can just run like so, with no `eval`:

```
wait_command
```

---

To restate again, a bit more clearly: **Exported functions are just environment variables with special names and values**. If you create an environment variable whose name starts with `BASH_FUNC_` and ends with `%%`, and whose value starts with `() {`, you just created an exported function, which will be available to run in shells started with it in the environment.

---

Thus, in your `.yml` file, you can use something like this:

```
environment: {BASH_FUNC_wait_command%%: '() {  [ $(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent
    --output /dev/null http://elastic:9200/_cat/health?h=st) = 200 ]'}
```

Comment: docker-compose allows me to export env_vars, I am not sure it I can define a function inside the docker-compose.yml parameters

Comment: This is my point: Exported functions are nothing but environment variables with special names (starting with `BASH_FUNC_` and ending with `%%`) and values (starting with `() {`). If you can create an arbitrary environment variable, you can create an exported function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `eval`. Instead, just get the status

```
status=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://elastic:9200/_cat/health?h=st)"
```

then test it directly.

```
is_ready () {
    [[ $status -eq 200 ]]
}
```

Comment: I need the test to be in the **WAIT_COMMAND** as a string in environment variable:

    WAIT_COMMAND="$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://elastic:9200/_cat/health?h=st) -eq 200"

How to evaluate that code inside the is_ready function?

Comment: @rochacbruno, that's not an environment variable, it's just a regular shell variable. And since it's neither an environment variable nor a shell built-in, you shouldn't be naming it with all caps.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know, but when exported by the docker-compose it will be available as an ENV VAR

Comment: Ahh! This is useful context in terms of understanding *why* you want to do things the way you proposed. (Not that that approach is correct -- this is what exported functions are for).

Comment: I edited the question separating the VARS to be more clear.. thanks